# How to reduce the size of ndarray after each iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an ndarray A as:

```
A =[  1
      3
      5
      2
      4
   ]
```

What I want to do is:

Select the highest value of A in the first iteration and store it in another list B, and delete that element after storing. Again Select the highest value from the remaining items in A and store it in B, and so on untill A becomes empty.

I have the following code for it:

```
B = []
for I in range(len(A)):
    temp = []
    p = A.max()
    temp.append(p)
    A.remove(A[i])
    B.append(temp)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: A.remove(A[i])
ndarray has no attribute remove()
```

Comment: Did you even check the docs for a remove method? Or just guess that it's like a list?  Why not stick with lists?

Comment: You put the max in temp, but attempt to remove the i`th on from the array.  Make this work with a list, and then worry about do the same with an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a list version of the code (that works):

```
In [36]: A = [1,3,5,2,4]
In [37]: B = []
In [38]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     p = max(A)
    ...:     B.append(p)
    ...:     A.remove(p)
    ...:     
In [39]: A
Out[39]: []
In [40]: B
Out[40]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The array equivalent (not recommended):

```
In [41]: A = [1,3,5,2,4]
In [42]: A = np.array(A)
In [43]: B = []
In [44]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     j = np.argmax(A)
    ...:     B.append(A[j])
    ...:     A = np.delete(A,j)
    ...:     
In [45]: A
Out[45]: array([], dtype=int64)
In [46]: B
Out[46]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

`np.delete` isn't the same as `.remove`.  It works by index, not value.  Thus I have to use `argmax` to find the index of the max, not max value itself.  `delete` doesn't work in-place.  It's a complex function that returns a new array (most likely by concatenating `A[:j]` and `A[j+1:]`)

```
In [50]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     j = np.argmax(A)
    ...:     B.append(A[j])
    ...:     A = np.concatenate((A[:j],A[j+1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy arrays have a fixed size.  They are not resizable, which means that to truly "remove" an element requires copying all the other elements to a new array, which is very inefficient and defeats the purpose of using NumPy in the first place.

Instead, consider what your code actually does: it produces a sorted list.  This will do the same thing, much faster and with less code:

```
np.sort(A)[::-1].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks John. You are right that it produces a sorted list, But I want it done in my way.

Comment: @Anstudent: Why?